# MySQL and NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, xampp, localhost

I'm trying to link my code to my database and I keep getting this error. I'm using a mac and XAMPP on port localhost:8080 remote port 80. I can't imagine why I keep getting this error. Code seems to be correct. Hopefully someone can help me because, my lecturer isn't available and i'm hoping to understand this and get it working. My database seems to be set up correctly as well. There is also information i manually put into the tables hoping it would show up on http://localhost:3000

[image]

https://github.com/kamrantrea/serverSide2019-/tree/master/tutorial/weekFive

**undefined
/Users/admin/Desktop/nodejsmysqltest/routes/index.js:8
        connection.query(`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC`, function (err, rows, fields) {
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

It appears getConnection invoked your callback with an error. Try adding error check at the beginning of the callback function:

```
    req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      if (err) return next(err);
```

*Posting this as an answer rather than a comment due to insufficient rep*

Comment: throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

ReferenceError: err is not defined .  This is the error i'm getting now